# How to share a local photo using React Expo Sharing.shareAsync?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to share a local file in React Expo using `Sharing.shareAsync()`.  Retrieved photo info using `MediaLibrary.getAssetInfoAsync()` (on Android):

```
"filename": "IMG_20200414_190459.jpg",
  "height": 2074,
  "id": "896",
  "localUri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200414_190459.jpg",
  "location": null,
  "mediaType": "photo",
  "modificationTime": 1586905500000,
  "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200414_190459.jpg",
  "width": 4608,
```

Calling `Sharing.shareAsync(photo.localUri, {mimeType: 'image/jpeg'}` I get the error `Failed to share the file: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200414_190459.jpg`. So I tried removing one of the slashes after `file:` and get the error `Not allowed to read file under given URL.`

App has `CAMERA_ROLL` and `CAMERA` permissions and app.json includes:

```
"android": {
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "CAMERA_ROLL",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ]
    }
```

Expo docs say I should be able to share a local file. Not sure what I'm doing wrong or what to try next. TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this may be a bug in the `Sharing` API. You can work around it for now by copying the file to your document directory and then sharing from there. Here's an example: https://snack.expo.io/@notbrent/share-media-library-photo

Relevant code from that example below:

```
// Placeholder for getting asset from MediaLibrary
let results = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({ first: 1 });
let asset = results.assets[0];

// Use FileSystem to copy the image from its original location to the app document directory
let assetUriParts = asset.uri.split("/");
let assetName = assetUriParts[assetUriParts.length - 1];
let uri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}/${assetName}`;
await FileSystem.copyAsync({
  from: asset.uri,
  to: uri,
});

// Share the image from the uri that you copied it to
Sharing.shareAsync(uri);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem with the share API. You can get over this using the expo-image-manipulation.
As an example:

```
import * as ImageManipulator from "expo-image-manipulator";

const openShareDialogAsync = async () => {
    let imageProc = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(yourImageUri);
    // this returns an object including the uri
    await Sharing.shareAsync(imageProc.uri);
}
```